# Examples of private key leakage / compromised keypair resulting in certificate revocation

Tags: certificate, private-key, ca

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this kind of question. I am looking for some examples of private key leakage or compromised keypair (via insider attack, configuration mistake, etc.) that lead to certificate revocation. I am particularly looking for cases when CA was compromised but can also use info on leaf certificates.

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question, it belongs on [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk is right about the wrong place.
Nonetheless, here are a few https://www.cnet.com/news/privacy/adobe-to-revoke-code-signing-certificate/
https://www.itpro.co.uk/security/malware/365023/nvidia-certificates-sign-malware-bypassing-windows-detection
https://www.theregister.com/2015/09/18/d_link_code_signing_key_leak/ 
https://threatpost.com/final-report-diginotar-hack-shows-total-compromise-ca-servers-103112/77170/